# Most efficient way to delete images

Tags: java, android, android-file

I have a small app that takes a picture with the device camera and then saves it with a random integer name in a folder on the `sdcard`. Upon reentering  the app I populate a `horizontal scroll view` with the images from `sdcard` folder with the `folder.listFiles()` and then setting the returned list to an `ArrayList` then use `BitmapFactory.decode` to turn the file paths into bitmaps then set them to an imageview as such

```
 ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageDir.getPath());
 iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Now I need help in finding out how to delete each bitmap if a user long presses one of these images. I have been doing a bit of brainstorming but not quite sure how to approach my situation. I figure I have to use `file.delete()` but not sure how I would get the path of the currently pressed image. Thanks for taking a minute to read.

Comment: You can save file path to the ImageView tag. iv.setTag(imageDir.getPath()). Then you can use it iv.getTag()

Comment: @user527759 Good idea, but `contentDescription` serves this purpose. set path in `contentDescription` and get the path from `contentDescription` of image

Comment: So `contentDescription` will be added when I am loading the new views or is it stored when saving the images? Thanks for the replies.